# Accessing controller data in order to pass local variables for rendering a haml partial in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to render a partial within a view. I have the following code in my view which calls upon the haml document being rendered:

```
= render :partial => 'data_popups/events'
```

However I need to pass local variables so 'undefined local variable' is solved. The controller, which contains all of the data, is under dataPopupsController#events ... is there anyway to access the data so I can pass local variables to the partial? Any and all help is welcome. Cheers~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the data is available in your outer view, you can pass it to a partial using the `locals` option. For instance, if this was on your home page, you could pass the data to the controller like this...

```
# app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @data = Model.get_data
  end
end
```

Then, in your view, pass that `@data` into your partial using the `locals` option of the `render` method:

```
# app/views/pages/home.html.erb
<%= render :partial => 'data_popups/events', :locals => { :data => @data } %>
```

Comment: Nice, so how could I make the data available in my outer view via controller?

Comment: I expanded my answer to show making the data available via the controller.

Comment: so if I have the following partial: events/show/_sidebar.html.haml ... would I have to include this code in the events_controller? Currently, I am querying and accessing the variables in the data_popups_controller.

Comment: You only need to retrieve the data in the controller action (method) that loads the outer view...doesn't matter where the partial is from

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your controller code, here's a basic example of what you could do:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @data = User.get_data
  end
end

# views/users/index.html.erb

<%= @data.some_method %>
<%= render 'data_popups/events', :locals => { :data => @data } %>

# views/data_popups/_events.html.erb

<%= data.some_other_method %>
```

Notice that when you pass `@data` as a local to 'data_popups/events', you now reference the local variable as `data`.